# Android Can't Answer incoming call with native SIP

Tags: android, asterisk, samsung-mobile

I currently have a Note 3 hooked up to an asterisk server. This server powers other phones, but for some reason the native android sip client does not work. I can make calls, but when I have an incoming call, I can only decline. If I try to answer, it just silences the call. Also, if I try to slide to answer, the screen doesn't go away, the phone is just on silenced, but the call is still coming in. I've tried this on 3g AND wifi. There's two other asterisk clients on my wifi network and both work perfectly, so I don't think it's a firewall setting. Any ideas?

```
[123]
type=friend
username=me
secret=password
host=dynamic
context=mycontext
nat=yes
qualify=yes
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=gsm
allow=ulaw
```

Answer (score 1):

Are asterisk server and android cellphone in the same network? If true, try use

```
 nat=no
```

option.
Also, uncheck all NAT-features in Android sip-client if any checked.